# Div id empty when grabbing it during a scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to grab the id of a div during a scroll so that I can trigger a GA event to track who is scrolling to what section of the site. Here is the .js code I'm using:

```
function scrollDetect(){
        var triggerPoint= Math.round($(window).height() / 2);
            var sections =  document.getElementsByClassName("section");
            var triggeredSectionArray = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++){
                triggeredSectionArray[i] = true;
            }

$(document).scroll(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++){
        if(($(sections[i]).offset().top-$(window).scrollTop()) < triggerPoint && triggeredSectionArray[i] != false){
            var tempElem = sections[i];
            alert(sections[i].id);
            triggeredSectionArray[i] = false;

        }
    }});

}
```

scrollDetect() is called on body load, and it detects when the top of the div is past the trigger point (I'm still deciding on what I want that trigger point to be exactly) - but the id itself is coming up as an empty string. All of the divs have ids explicitly defined in the tag, and when I try setting the id it does so as well.

Comment: And the html looks like?

Comment: a jsfiddle would be really helpful

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. The div was nested and the child had the id, not the "section".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP, in the comments, said he'd already solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your document starts with:  so that jQuery can calculate the height of the window correctly and try this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var bottom = top + $(window).height();

    $(".section").each(function() {
      if ($(this).offset().top >= top && $(this).offset().top <= bottom) {
        console.log($(this).attr('id')); //Change this to GA tasks
      }
    });
  });
});
```